# Redis data lost on host restart

Tags: docker, ubuntu, redis

I have docker container with redis server running on ubuntu server that keep track of a counter that is incremented by a node js app also running in a container.

It works well when i launch my ubuntu host all the containers redis + nodeapp are automatically started.

Visiting an url, I am able to increment the counter with the node app.
I see the counter in the redis server incremented throw a redis client and the web page.

But I have an issue:

1. If i **restart the host machine** then when the *container* restart (i use `restart:always` to build my containers to restart them on host reboot) the counter in the redis server drop to 0(the counter was not saved).
2. I noticed that if i increment the counter to a certain value let’s say 20 and if i **stop the the container redis from the host** and **start** that container again the counter is **saved** to 20. And **after the reboot of the host** the counter doesn’t start at 0 but that previous value 20 so the counter was saved.

So my question is how to save the data (counter in redis container) when the host machine is restarted ? Why in my case the only way to have the data saved is to stop the container using the docker command stop ?

Comment: Sounds like Redis is not flushing to disk. This behaviour can be customized, see the following container documentation: https://github.com/jamesbrink/docker-redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen http://redis.io/topics/persistence ?

> By default Redis saves snapshots of the dataset on disk, in a binary
>   file called dump.rdb. You can configure Redis to have it save the
>   dataset every N seconds if there are at least M changes in the
>   dataset, or you can manually call the SAVE or BGSAVE commands. For
>   example, this configuration will make Redis automatically dump the
>   dataset to disk every 60 seconds if at least 1000 keys changed:

```
save 60 1000
```